# servlet page shows blank when accessed later

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, jdbc, tomcat7

I have a strange issue with **servlet page**. I have simple web application which contains just a servlet.I deployed it in `Tomcat 7`. When user enters url, the servlet should get directly executed, get the data from the database and print the output. But it shows blank page after some time. When I undeploy and deploy, it shows data. After some time when I access the page, it shows blank page. Then again when I redeploy, it shows data. Can someone please let me know how to resolve this? I have no clue why it happens. Below is my code.

I am using `mysql` database.`mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar` added in lib folder and added to buildpath.

```
public class Homeservlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    static final String mysqldblink = "************";
    static final String mysqlUsername = "username";
    static final String mysqlPassword = "pw";

    Connection connection =null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Homeservlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException 
    {
    super.init(config);

    try{

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(mysqldblink,
                mysqlUsername, mysqlPassword);

        stmt = connection.createStatement();

    }
    catch(Exception E)
    {
        E.printStackTrace();
    }

    }

    @Override
    public void service(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response)
    {
        PrintWriter pw = null;

        try {
            String query = "querytogetdata";
            pw = response.getWriter();

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

            while(rs.next())
            {
                pw.println(rs.getString(1));
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try{    
                pw.close();

            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }   

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy(  ) {
        // Close the connection
          try {  

              if (connection != null)
                  connection.close(  );

              if(stmt != null)
                 stmt.close();

          } catch (SQLException ignore) { }
      }     

}
```

Comment: why resultset is not closed? you are using same connection and statement.

Comment: @Braj I believe when rs is iterated, then resultset gets automatically closed. I closed statement in destroy() method. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: So instead of overriding `doGet()` or `doPost()` you prefer to override `service()` method, why? `service()` method internally calls `doGet()` or `doPost()` based on request method type.

Comment: I think that you should look up your logs. There you can find something interest. Besides, don't forget that servlet is always in one instance and if it sometime works sometimes not maybe some problems occur in its fields.

Comment: @Braj Because I want the page to be shown as soon as someone accesses the url. If I use doGet() or doPost(), it's not showing anything automatically.

Comment: Your assumption is completely wrong. even if you use `doGet()` or `doPost()` it shows the page whenever it is accessed.

Comment: @Braj Might be as I am beginner in java web-app. As far as I understood, I followed this. Can you please let me know how it has to be done?

Comment: If you are hitting this servlet directly by entering the URL in browser window then its a GET request or if you are calling it from any form submission having method attribute as post then it's a POST request and based on request servlet methods are called. It might help you,  [Java Servlet Technology](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135475.html)

Comment: you are using single connection that will impact the other users that access the same page simultaneously. Instead create a connection whenever required and just close it when finished. use connection pool for good performance. It might help you [My ConnctionUtil Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22999830/servlet-server-side-initialization-code-in-gwt/23006184#23006184)

Comment: Actually I've never seen such driver before, what version of db are you using?

Comment: @Braj Yes, I want to hit the servlet directly by entering the URL. Remaining part I know.I think there is some db connectivity issue after some time when the deployment happens. Am I coding it in correct way about the db connection?

Comment: @RomanC I edited the driver name.

Comment: @Braj I am sorry, I have seen your answer which you linked. I am unable to understand how to replace my code(which has mysql and using tomcat) with that code and how to use that connectionutil in my servlet

Comment: That will not resolve your issue, its just for further improvement in your code. Can you try it again after moving the code in overridden `doGet()` from `service()` method and just remove `service()` method. create the connection and statement in `doGet()` rather that in `init()` method.

Comment: @Braj Thanks, I moved the service() code to doGet(). It works at the moment, but I don't know whether it works later. How can I improve the db connection thing now?

Comment: Sounds good, I have already share you a link. use connection pool and prepared statement instead of statement.

Comment: @Braj Yes, thanks. But I am not getting how to use them in my servlet code and where to place that datasource tags content. Anyways thanks.

Comment: No worries take your time, just read it more on Google. Don't do simply copy-paste, try to learn it first.